# Can't bring Python 3 (3.5) into venv

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, virtualenv

I am trying to create an python app with Heroku and VirtualEnv. I created the folder structure. and I have these files:

requirements.txt

```
j-database-url==0.4.0
Django==1.9.2
gunicorn==19.4.5
psycopg2==2.6.1
whitenoise==2.0.6
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.5.1
```

I Have both python 2.7 and 3.5 installed on my dev machine (OS X). `python` runs `/usr/bin/python` and `python3` runs `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

I then set up `virtualenv` on my folder.

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Two problems:

1. The python copied to my venv/bin/python is 2.7 and not 3.5. How do I force virtualenv to copy over python 3.5?
2. python from command line still points to the python 2.7 - Why isn't this changing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the default virtualenv installed is the python 2 one. Try creating the VirtualEnv with:

```
$ pyhton3 -m venv virtaulenv_name
```

then activate your virtaulEnv with:

```
$ source virtualenv_name/bin/activate
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Yep. that worked. thanks !